# C++ rand() function is not working on MPI

Tags: c++, random

I have an interesting situation here.

I've include the libraries `#include <stdlib.h>` which is suppose to allowed me to use `rand()`

In the same time I've used 2 different solution, one with `std::rand()` and one just with `rand()` in both of this cases I have declared in my top of program `using namespace std`.

But still I get this error:

> Can't resolve variable 'rand'

And here it's my code:

```
void makeAB() {
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_ROWS_A; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < NUM_COLUMNS_A; j++) {
            int i = std::rand();
            mat_a[i][j] = rand() % 10;//i + j;
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
here is CMakeList.txt

```
 cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(MPI_Project)


find_package(MPI REQUIRED)
include_directories(${MPI_INCLUDE_PATH})

SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER mpicc)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER mpicxx)

set_source_files_properties(main.c PROPERTIES LANGUAGE CXX)


set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(MPI_Project ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Comment: What happens if you use `cstdlib` instead?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but how big is `mat_a`? What *is* `mat_a`? Is `NUM_ROWS_A` equal to or larger than [`RAND_MAX`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/RAND_MAX)?

Comment: I've try using and that and it's said `Unused import statement`

Comment: Have you tried `::rand()` to explicitly call the non namespaced version?

Comment: yeh the index is ok... but I cant declare even that `int i = std::rand();` and this is not a problem of index..

Comment: @Mircea Who said that? That's one compiler message that I don't recognize.

Comment: @SimonKraemer what do you mean?

Comment: @Mircea *"Unused import statement"* is certainly not a (at least common) c++ error - Looks like a java error actually.

Comment: Write `mat_a[i][j] = ::rand() % 10;` instead of `mat_a[i][j] = rand() % 10;`. That makes it more clear that you are referring to the version not in a namespace. BTW: `Unused import statement` is probably only a warning that may be even wrong - have you tried if it works?

Comment: The messages you get ("Can't resolve variable 'rand'" and "Unused import statement") doesn't make much sense for a C++ ***compiler***. Do you get these errors when you ***compile*** the code? Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us? And please edit the question to include the *complete* error output, preferably copy-paste the whole build output as text into the question body, without editing.

Comment: Do you use `#include <stdlib.h>` and `#include <cstdlib>` at the same time? If yes: Please remove the  `#include <stdlib.h>` one.

Comment: Are you using CLion?

Comment: yes @SimonKraemer I'm using CLion

Comment: Try the fix described here https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206607185-CLion-not-recognizing-method-names-from-includes

Comment: And I've use and just one... and together... it's the same

Comment: Then are these "error" messages from the CLion IDE, or from when you build the program? My guess it's from the IDE. Which version of Clion are you using?

Comment: Yeh, I've build the program using CLion, and I've used CLion 2016.2.3

Comment: and yes @SimonKraemer I've put ::rand instead of rand and it's exactly the same..

Comment: Note that once you built once, you can not change the compiler. If you need to set the `CMAKE_*_COMPILER` variables, do it in the settings. Go to "Settings" -> "Build, Execution, Deployment" -> "CMake", and add e.g. `-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=mpicxx" in the "CMake options" text box.

Answer (score 0):

Including `stdlib.h` doesn't namespace `rand` under `std` (because it's a C header, not a C++ header; it doesn't even know what a namespace is). That's what the C++ wrapped headers are for, [in this case `cstdlib`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdlib). If you want namespaced `rand`, use `#include <cstdlib>`, not `#include <stdlib.h>`.

Given you're using CLion, odds are you named your C++ file with an extension it recognizes as a C extension, [which causes problems for C++ specific includes](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206607185-CLion-not-recognizing-method-names-from-includes). Rename the file with a `.cpp` extension, or, per the previous link, change your `CMakeList.txt` file to make it explicitly set the language for the `.c` file to be C++, changing a hacky line like this one:

```
set_source_files_properties(NAMEOFCFILE.c PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "-x c++")
```

(that just adds compiler flags without properly informing CLion that it's C++) to

```
set_source_files_properties(NAMEOFCFILE.c PROPERTIES LANGUAGE CXX)
```

which informs CLion properly.

Comment: I've try using and that and it's said `Unused import statement`

Comment: @Mircea: A number of IDEs apparently get this "Unused import statement" wrong. Does it work aside from that warning? That said, "Unused import statement" is an odd warning, this isn't an import, it's an include. What IDE/compiler is telling you this?

Comment: I've delete stdlib and i've let just cstdlib, it's still unused and I have the same error

Comment: @Mircea: Is the source file actually named with a `.cpp` extension? Apparently [CLion will have issues if a C file uses C++ includes](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206607185-CLion-not-recognizing-method-names-from-includes). But really, you need to specify what you're using. Is it the IDE? The compiler? What?

Comment: @Mircea: You're going to need to look at your build config then. I can't say what's wrong, but CLion is apparently picky about this sort of thing. The code is correct with `#include <cstdlib>`, it's your build process/IDE config that's wrong.

Comment: Ok so... I've add that line, and I've edit my question with changes..  but I have the same problem, and about the **cstdlib** after I've let just `cstdlib` and I've delete `stdlib` CLion was ask me to use the import with stdlib... I don't know why but he cant find the rand function with that include...

Comment: and my file name it's already with `.cpp`, even if in that line `set_source_files_properties(main.c PROPERTIES LANGUAGE CXX)` I will use main.cpp or main.c it's the same thing